# horizontal to vertical in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the sample code below;

```
var myarray= [],
myarray2=[];
var L=100;
for(j =0; j< 4;j++){
    for(i =0; i<4;i++){        
       myarray.push([L]);
       L=L+100;
    }
    myarray2.push(myarray);
    alert(myarray2[j]);
}
```

The output will be

```
100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,100,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600
```

Is it possible to sort the values like below in an array within an array?

```
100, 500, 900, 1300
200, 600, 1000, 1400
300, 700, 1100, 1500
400, 800, 1200, 1600
```

I would appreciate any help....thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `myarray2` really supposed to contain 4 references to the same `myarray`?

Comment: Are you wanting to create the array in that format or alter the flat array to that format?

Comment: Why don't you create that 2d-array you want as result in the first place?

Comment: I need just a little more information. Are you looking to achieve is in an alert message of would you be open to an HTML approach. Also are you trying to arrang these in colums that are no longer than 4 or in no more than 4 columns no matter the length?

Comment: I just made an example of 4..it can be dynamic Bergi.

Comment: yes instead of horizontal...I want it vertical stored in an array Xotic750

Comment: I tried using 2dim but I can't seem to find a way Bergi

Comment: @pongs: No, that's not what I meant. Have a look at `JSON.stringify(myarray2, null, 2)` to see what data structure you are actually creating.

Comment: I want it stored in an array without using html tags Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will convert from your flat array into the multidimentional array that you have described.

Javascript

```
var array = "100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,100,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600".split(",");
var grouping = 4;
var result = [];

array.forEach(function (element, index) {
    var group = index % grouping;
    var temp = result[group];

    if (!Array.isArray(temp)) {
        temp = [];
    }

    temp.push(element);
    result[group] = temp;
});

console.log(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/HSk9x/)

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I am going to assume that it is `myarray`, as suggested by @bergi, that you wish to convert and not `myarray2`. Based on this assumption here is a modified solution

Javascript

```
var myarray = [],
    myarray2 = [];
var L = 100;
for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        myarray.push([L]);
        L = L + 100;
    }

    myarray2.push(myarray);
}

var columns = 4;
var result = [];
var flattened = myarray.toString().split(",");
var length = flattened.length;
var rows = Math.round(length / columns);

flattened.forEach(function (element, index) {
    var group = index % rows;
    var temp = result[group];

    if (!Array.isArray(temp)) {
        temp = [];
    }

    temp.push(element);
    result[group] = temp;
});

console.log(result);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ux3xA/)

Here is an alternative flatten method

```
var flattened = myarray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});
```

if you don't like

```
var flattened = myarray.toString().split(",");
```

And for interest only sake, the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/flatten-with-reduced-vs-tostring-and-split) on the above flatten methods.

Comment: Actually, his `myArray` is `[[100],[200],[300],[400],[500],[600],[700],[800],[900],[1000],[1100],[1200],[1300],[1400],[1500],[1600]]` - that `array` string is only the output if you alert it.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I didn't look at what he actually created, just what he stated.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate an array of arrays from scratch.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 4; 
var result = [];

for(j = 0; j < y; j++) {
  result[j] = [];
  for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    result[j].push((j % y + i*y) * 100);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Yields:

```
[ [   0, 400,  800, 1200, 1600, 2000, 2400, 2800, 3200, 3600 ],
  [ 100, 500,  900, 1300, 1700, 2100, 2500, 2900, 3300, 3700 ],
  [ 200, 600, 1000, 1400, 1800, 2200, 2600, 3000, 3400, 3800 ],
  [ 300, 700, 1100, 1500, 1900, 2300, 2700, 3100, 3500, 3900 ] ]
```

You can adjust the number of entries by changing x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a one liner using lodash or underscore JavaScript,

```
let arr=[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,100,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600];
let len=4;  // Can be varied upon your requirement
let soln= _.unzip( _.chunk(arr,len)).map((x)=>{return (x!==undefined)?x:[];});
console.log(soln); // This will print resultant array
```

This will print the following result.

> [ [ 100, 500, 900, 1300 ],
>
> [ 200, 600, 100, 1400 ],
>
> [ 300, 700, 1100, 1500 ],
>
> [ 400, 800, 1200, 1600 ] ]